# How to create a sub project via REST API in TeamCity 8?

Tags: continuous-integration, teamcity

I'm trying to create a sub project using the rest api, as seen in: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/REST+API+Plugin#RESTAPIPlugin-GeneralInfo

I have a root project with id="abcd", when i do a post with the following command:

```
        <newProjectDescription 
            name='test' 
            id='abcd_test' 
            parentProject='id:abcd' 
            copyAllAssociatedSettings='true'>
        </newProjectDescription>
```

to http://myteamcity.foo.com/httpAuth/app/rest/projects.

The project is created as a root project but it should be created as a sub project of "abcd" instead.

I'm using TeamCity Professional 8.0.2 (build 27482).

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

there are little bug in our documentation, please use xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<newProjectDescription name="Inner" id="Outer_Inner">
    <parentProject id="Outer"/>
</newProjectDescription>
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<newProjectDescription name="Inner" id="Outer_Inner">
    <parentProject locator="id:Outer"/>
</newProjectDescription>
```

for creating new project Inner as sub-project of Outer

For copy action just add `<sourceProject locator="id:CopyFrom"/>` tag and `copyAllAssociatedSettings` field.